# Generate QRcode in a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, qr-code

I'm trying to generate a QR code on a windows form and trying to set it to an image box.
I got the following code from [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/krishnasarala/generating-barcode-in-C-Sharp/) source and the related files from [here](http://www.onbarcode.com/winforms/qr_code_generator.html).

```
            private void GenerateQrcode(string _data, string _filename)
    {
        QRCode qrcode = new QRCode();
        qrcode.Data = _data;
        qrcode.DataMode = QRCodeDataMode.Byte;
        qrcode.UOM = UnitOfMeasure.PIXEL;
        qrcode.X = 3;
        qrcode.LeftMargin = 0;
        qrcode.RightMargin = 0;
        qrcode.TopMargin = 0;
        qrcode.BottomMargin = 0;
        qrcode.Resolution = 72;
        qrcode.Rotate = Rotate.Rotate0;
        qrcode.ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Gif;
        qrcode.drawBarcode(_filename);
    }
```

I want to know where this file is being created. What do I have to pass as file name, just a string as a name or the path of the directory which the file is being created. 
How can I display the created file in a picture box? like this?

```
       pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example on http://www.onbarcode.com/csharp/qr-code-generator.html says:

```
// Generate QR-Code and encode barcode to gif format
qrcode.ImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif;
qrcode.drawBarcode("C:\\qrcode.gif"); 
/*
You can also call other drawing methods to generate barcodes          
public void drawBarcode(Graphics graphics);
public void drawBarcode(string filename);    
public Bitmap drawBarcode();
public void drawBarcode(Stream stream);             
*/
```